# R2 bucket cloudflare - list based on a key specification

Tags: javascript, nosql, storage, cloudflare, bucket

I am having trouble finding a documentation for the R2 bucket. GPT can not help me as it was cut-off in 2021.
Here's the problem. I have never worked with an unrelational storage/db such as R2.
I would like to retrieve a list of data based on a certain value in the keys.
This is a wrangler worker hosted on cloudflare binded with an R2 bucket

```
const r2 = env.MY_BUCKET;
async function saveMaster(codeMaster) {
    try {
      const masterName = codeMaster.name;
      const type = "master";
      const masterKey = {
        masterName,
        type
      };
      const result = await r2.put(masterKey, codeMaster);
      return result;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error saving data:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }

async function getCodeMasters() {

  // code to fetch all "masters" from r2 where each key has a type : "master"
}
```